# Exporting used shapefiles and saving them in separate folder using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

In my project, I have a lot of shapefiles with different information. I won’t need all of those shapefiles, but just a few.

I would like to know if there is a way to export all the used shapefiles in my project and save it in a separate folder? That way, I would just have to copy one folder, without having to select every shapefile one by one. Another advantage would be, that in case of a change in my folder, I would just have to change it one time and I could use my origin information in different projects as well.

I heard that this is possible in ArcGIS. I am not sure if I could express myself clearly, but I hope so.

I use QGIS 12.2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QConsolidate plugin does exactly that 
http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qconsolidate/

Comment: that would be amazing if it works... But I can't find that plugin... Does it has another name too?

Comment: It is an experimental plugin, so enable experimental plugins in your plugin manager and it will show up.

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you so much! I read that if possible, we shouldn't use this plugin, why is that?

Comment: Where did you read that? it maybe because it is experimental and doesn't work with all type of layers (databases etc.)

Comment: Actually in the plugin manager, where i can enable experimental plugins is written, that they don't suggest the installation besides for test purpose... so I was just curious why... Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: Experimental plugins maybe new or not actively maintained. So it is mostly a warning to users to be careful. If it works for you, you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Plugin Batch Save Layers
Save open vector layers as different file types simultaneously

Comment: Adding some additional information in here to let give us some context and explanation as to what you are doing would be helpful.  From reading this, as it stands, I'm unsure what you mean. Please edit for clarity.